# Issue with Demonstration of covariant derivative

Tags: tensors

I need help to understand the definition of derivative covariant. Below the demonstration of the $j-th$ component of $\nabla_{X_{i}} V$, i.e under the form : $\nabla_{X_{i}}V = \left(X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}\right)e^{j}$ with $\left(X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}\right)\;\equiv\;\left(X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}\right)_{j}$

The basis vectors (and dual basis) used are defined by : $X_{i}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$ and $e^{j}=\text{d}x^{j}$.

Here's a valid calculation to get this $j-th$ component :

$$\begin{align}
\nabla_{X_{i}}V &\,=\, \nabla_{X_{i}}(V_{a}e^{a}) \,=\, (\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{a})e^{a} + V_{a} (\nabla_{X_{i}}e^{a}) \\[0.1cm]
 & \,=\, (X_{i}V_{a})e^{a} - V_{a} (\Gamma^{a}_{ij}e^{j}) \\[0.1cm]
 & \,=\, \left(X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}\right) e^{j} 
\end{align}$$

So $\left(X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}\right)$ represents this $j-th$ component.

However, I don't understand the part where there is the equality :

$$(\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{a})e^{a} = (X_{i}V_{a})e^{a}$$

i.e,

$$(\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{a}) = (X_{i}V_{a})\quad\quad\quad\text{equation 1}$$

From the classic definition that I know, one can write :

$(\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{a}) \;=\; X_{i}V_{a} - V_{l}\Gamma^{l}_{ia}\quad\quad\quad\text{equation 2}$

Why does term $V_{l}\Gamma^{l}_{ia}$ disappears in $\text{equation (1)}$ relatively to $\text{equation (2)}$??

Thanks for your explanation.

**UPDATE 1**

But in the following demontsration :

$$\begin{align}
\nabla_{X_{i}}V &\,=\, \nabla_{X_{i}}(V_{a}e^{a}) \,=\, (\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{a})e^{a} + V_{a} (\nabla_{X_{i}}e^{a}) \\[0.1cm]
 & \,=\, (X_{i}V_{a})e^{a} - V_{a} (\Gamma^{a}_{ij}e^{j}) \\[0.1cm]
 & \,=\, \left(X_{i}V_{j} - V_{a}\Gamma^{a}_{ij}\right) e^{j} 
\end{align}$$

We have :

$$(\nabla_{X_{i}}e^{a})=(\Gamma_{il}^{a} e^{l})\quad\quad\quad \text{equation 3}$$

(I understand how to prove this `equation 3`)

and for $(\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{a})$, I get :

$$(\nabla_{X_{i}}V_{a}) = (X_{i}V_{a})\quad\quad\quad\text{equation 4}$$

Why, in `equation 4`, Chrsitoffel symbols have disappeared ?

When you talk about orthonormal basis, you mean : $X_{i}\,e^{a}=\delta_{ia}$ ?? and what's the link between the removing of Christoffel's symbols in `equation 4` ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the Christoffel symbols vanish in this situation because the coordinates chosen are orthonormal. In particular, when parallel transporting around in such a coordinate system, the parallel transport maps in any particular direction have derivative $0$ - the vector fields are actually parallel -  and this makes all the Christoffel symbols $0$.

Comment: Alfred Yerger: coul you take a look please in my **UPDATE 1** of my first message, I need precisions, thanks